# while iam calling this len(Name) function getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable why it was getting?

Tags: python

```
Name = "Michael Jackson"

type(Name)

> str
```

Here is my question

```
len(Name)
```

-As per the guides and blogs and examples len(object) it has to generate the lenght of the string Michael Jackson is a word in str format hence the output must be 15 when we using the len() function.

-Can someone please let me know the once the String is defined as "Name" when we call `len(Name)` it has to generate the total characters of the Name= "Michael Jackson"; 15?

- while using this below line and running getting error message.

'len(Name)'

'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'

why iam getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you defined a built-in function `len` as a local variable, particularly string type. Thus when you use the function again, it is not a function anymore, it is a string variable. Therefore, you cannot use a string variable `len` as a function anymore.

**Built-in function without redefinition:**

```
Name = "Michael Jackson"
type(Name)
len(Name)
```

> 15

**Built-in function with redefinition:**

```
Name = "Michael Jackson"
type(Name)
len = 'hi'
len(Name)
```

> ----> 7 len(Name)
>
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

**Solution:** You need to come back to the code, and make sure that you did not redefine the `len` function. If you do not find any line of redefinition, you might only restart your kernel of python. I hope it will work.